# How can share all list item in shareBody?

Tags: java, android

There is one list in my project. I can share and make message body of first `index`. But, I want to share all `list` `index`. How can I do it successfully?

I just tried like that. But, in this way it get last `index` of `list`. I couldn't make send as `ArrayList` also.

```
 for (i=0; i<cartList.size(); i++){
        Cart cartL = cartList.get(i);
        img = cartL.getImage();
        title = cartL.getTitle();
        market = cartL.getMarket();
        cost = cartL.getCost();
```

This is my code work now. It sends only first index:

```
db = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
        cartList = db.getdata();

        Cart cartL = cartList.get(0);
        img = cartL.getImage();
        title = cartL.getTitle();
        market = cartL.getMarket();
        cost = cartL.getCost();


        CartAdapter myAdapter = new CartAdapter(getActivity(), cartList);
        recyclerViewCart.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        imageShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                String shareBody = "Ürün Adı:  " + title + "  Market:  " + market + "   Fiyat:  " + cost;
                String shareSubject="Alışveriş Listesi";

                sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
                sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, shareSubject);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Paylaş"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make shareBody with all items inside. This for will work but at this point you are pulling out the last element and not all of it. You must assign the data to shareBody in each loop.

```
String shareBody = "";
for (i=0; i<cartList.size(); i++){
        Cart cartL = cartList.get(i);
        img = cartL.getImage();
        title = cartL.getTitle();
        market = cartL.getMarket();
        cost = cartL.getCost();
shareBody += "Ürün Adı:  " + title + "  Market:  " + market + "   Fiyat:  " + cost;}
```

Better way is make json type and send as array :)